# Message: oci_execute(): ORA-01008: not all variables bound : Procedure call from codeIgniter 3.1.9

Tags: oracle, codeigniter, stored-procedures, procedure

Message:

> oci_execute(): ORA-01008: not all variables bound

while calling a stored procedure from the codeigniter version 3.1.9, I am getting ORA-01008: issue

```
$query = $this->db->query("CALL $procedureName(:NodeCode, :NodeName, :Address_1,:Address_2, :Address_3, :CityId,:Pin_Code,:ColoId, :Latitude, :LatDecimal,:LatDegree, :Longitude_1, :LongDecimal,:LongDegree,:UserName,:StatusMode,:ErrorCode, :ErrorMessage)", array(
    "NodeCode"=> "QQQ",
    "NodeName"=> "QQQ",
    "Address_1"=> "address_1",
    "Address_2"=> "address_2",
    "Address_3"=> "address_3",
    "CityId"=> 157,
    "Pin_Code"=> "125050",
    "ColoId"=> 3,
    "Latitude"=> "30:42",
    "LatDecimal"=> "78",
    "LatDegree"=> "29",
    "Longitude_1"=> "26:47",
    "LongDecimal"=> "82",
    "LongDegree"=> "75",
    "UserName"=> "fusion.support",
    "StatusMode"=> "ADD",
    "ErrorCode"=> "",
    "ErrorMessage"=> ""
));

$this->db->trans_complete();

if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {
    // Transaction failed
    $error = $this->db->error();
    echo $error['message'];
} else {
    // Transaction succeeded
}
```